How to retrieve attribution paths data via Google Analytics API?
I need help retrieving attribution paths data using the Google Analytics API.
Specifically, I'm looking to pull the following:
Metrics: Key events, Purchase revenue, Days to key events, and Touchpoints
Dimension: Default Channel Group
Support Link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10595568?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
Could someone please guide me on how to structure the API request to fetch this data?
Thank you in advance for your help!
